# Cannot get konsole to show the right characters for fancy powerline

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm using Kubuntu and the patched fonts for powerline are not working as expected...

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/33uvjvo.jpg]

The screenshot is from terminal Vim, but gVim has the same problem in my machine.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: use powerline's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a workaround:

It was not the font itself. It was some weird bug or incompatibility in the way they pointed to the unicode code points they want to use in the "fancy" setup, so I overrode the symbols and separators:

Add this to ~/.vimrc:

```
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
let g:Powerline_dividers_override = ['', '', '', '']
let g:Powerline_symbols_override = { 'BRANCH': '', 'LINE': '', 'RO': '' }
```

or:

```
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
let g:Powerline_dividers_override = ["\Ue0b0", "\Ue0b1", "\Ue0b2", "\Ue0b3"]
let g:Powerline_symbols_override = { 'BRANCH': "\Ue0a0", 'LINE': "\Ue0a1", 'RO': "\Ue0a2" }
```

Then run :PowerlineClearCache and restart Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Try install Input Mono Font (v.1.1 or higher) and you don't need patched font. You can grab in http://input.fontbureau.com.

Version 1.1 (2014‑09‑03)

- **Added glyphs for Powerline characters**        (U+E0A0–E0A2, U+E0B0–E0B3).
- Added glyph for high voltage sign character ⚡ (U+26A1).
- Added alternate curly bracket glyphs  for users who prefer simplified forms.
- Added alternate dotless zero glyph  for users who don’t want a dot or slash in the zero.
- Added zero width space ​(U+200B) and zero width no-break space ﻿(U+FEFF).
- Changed default line-height option to 1.2×

> In some terminals, [Powerline](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/) symbols may be misaligned or cut off (documented [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts/issues/31)). Due to differing interpretations of vertical metrics and rendering engines, there is no single solution; two different font sizes within the same app can produce different results. Increasing Input’s line-spacing in the [customization panel](http://input.fontbureau.com/download/?customize) can help you control its appearance.

Answer (score 0):

The powerline characters will not show if the locale is not configured to anything.
Plasma5 go to Settings->Regional Settings-> in the Region dropdown select your region.